# Intrusive Google Play Store advertisements appear as soon as I start charging my phone

Tags: google-play-store, 7.0-nougat, ads, popup

I get these types of full screen ads as soon as I charge my phone:

[image: Google Play Ad]

I don't even have to unlock the screen, the ad sound starts playing as soon as I plug in my phone. In order to get rid of it, I installed a third party app called `Blokada` and it worked and if I see which all ads are popping up, the app says that the ads are:

1. app.adjust.com
2. mobile.pipe.aria.microsoft.com

So I guess these ads are responsible for those intrusive popups. I have tried multiple antivirus applications but none of them showed that I have any virus/malware. Is there anyway I can remove these adwares from my phone ?

Comment: Does Add-ons Detector find anything unusual?

Comment: @acejavelin `Blokada` is an out of the play store ad-blocker. Sadly it has stopped working now and I get these ads every time I charge my phone.

Answer (score 10):

It isn't a Virus. So, no anti-virus or malware scanner will catch this.

It is just an app which adds lockscreen ads to your device while charging. These ads are set so that they only appear while charging. Some apps even advertise that this makes the device charge faster.

Such ads are included with many free apps and you need to find out which app is showing them on your lockscreen. The most usual culprits are - Avast Anti-virus (Yes!), ES File explorer (the probably stopped now), UC Browser, Xender, Clean Master, and many other so called *device booster*, battery booster, CPU booster, memory booster type apps.

I'm sorry but you'll have to figure it on your own from this point. It is impossible to pin-point a particular app because there are just so many of then which do this.

Comment: +1, good explanation. As OP already identified two networks: there are several [apps to detect libraries in apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules#group_443). So the list of possible culprits can be narrowed done to those e.g. containing an `Adjust` module (first network mentioned, and IMHO the most likely culprit here). Maybe you want to include that with your answer?

Comment: It might be useful to read this latest (2018/11/26) [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/eight-android-apps-2-billion-downloads-are-committing-ad-click-fraud) blog report about "Clean Master" and its ad-click actions.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that "email all in one" was causing this problem on my Samsung android phone. I uninstalled it, unplugged the charger  plugged it back in, and no ads popped up, nor the annoying "fast charge" option, which i never used, but the "Not now" box could not be selected because it was greyed out!